# ListView and GridView inside ScrollView. ScrollView won't scrolling

Tags: android, listview, gridview, scrollview

First of all i want to apollogize for my english, i am from Russia and i hope that google translater helps me to describe my problem=). 
So problem is - i have a gridView and ExpandableListView inside ScrollView, i know that i shouldn't put a something scrollable View inside ScrollView, but for my goal i cant find alternative. In my project i have a business catalog with categories(like "Electronics","Home&Garden","Motors" etc), and all i want to do is to put most popular categories into gridView (and add icons to them) and make scrollview to scroll it like single layout. But my scrollView won't scroll it, how i can do that?

my bizCatalog Actvivty:

[image]

my bizCatalog layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewSwitcher xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/bizSwitcher"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Загрузка списка..." />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/bizScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/bizFavoritesGrid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:columnWidth="90dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
        </GridView>

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/bizList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
        </ExpandableListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</ViewSwitcher>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the above by override the `dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` function for scroll view. inside this function send the events to your child listview. then also you need to override dispatchTouchEvent for your listview like this

```
  int[] location = new int[2];
  listView.getLocationOnScreen(location);

  if (e.getRawX() > location[0] && e.getRawX()< location[0] + listView.getWidth() &&
   e.getRawY() > location[1] && e.getRawY() < location[1] + listView.getHeight())
  {
    int[] checkListLoc = new int[2];

    listView.getLocationOnScreen(checkListLoc);
    var offset = checkListLoc[1] - (e.getRawY() - e.GetY());
    e.OffsetLocation(0, 0 - offset);

    listView.dispatchTouchEvent(e);
    return true;
 }
 return base.dispatchTouchEvent(e);
```

Comment: You have to deal with hell if you want adapter views in scroll view. I thought you didnot have any other choice

Answer (score 0):

Instead of GridView, use [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html).

Answer (score 0):

As per Android guidelines, you cannot use one scrollable layout into another. If you are using ScrollView then you ca not use ListView inside it. Because both of the layouts are scrollable. So please use any one to scroll your.

Answer (score 0):

Remove scroll view first. use listview and add gridview as footerview of listview. it will work great. Definitely solve your problem.

Comment: Ok, i'll try it(I did know that i can add gridview into listview header)